# Java "plainest" map implementation / linked map (NOT LinkedHashMap)

Tags: java, dictionary, linked-list

Just a quick question:

What is the "plainest" map implementation in java, meaning that it maintains its entries as a simple list of keys and values, without ordering, hashing or something else. Presumably this implementations iteration order would be the insertion order (like in `LinkedHashMap`), but not even that would be necessary for my use case. I would prefer a linked architecture (`O(1)` for adding) if existent.

I know that this would be extremely easy to implement on my own, but I just want to know if there is a "standard java" implemenation.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but perhaps you're looking for a List<[Pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html)>?

Comment: That is basically exactly the architecture I am looking for, but there are two problems to it:

1. `Pair` is not part of the java standard library (therefore not really the "java standard way")
2. It is a bit complicated to use (I would prefer a "clean" map implemetation)

Comment: List of Pair? I think it’s simple and starting with Java 7, there is now a class for this in standard Lib : javafx.util.Pair.
It is standard Java, now that JavaFx. (Sorry. I’m not comment because I don’t have enough reputation to comment)

Comment: **Why** are you looking so hard for this implementation?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I just want to know whether there is a standard java map implementation for this or if I should implement my own

Comment: You should not implement your own and should use `HashMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest imaginable implementation of `Map<K,T>` would be a wrapper class for a `List<Pair<K,T>>`.  Or to save memory, a wrapper for two lists or arrays of `K` and `T`.

The wrapper would need to implement the methods of `Map` as operations on the wrapped list.  It is not trivial.

> I just want to know if there is a "standard java" implementation.

There isn't an implementation in Java SE, and that is what "standard Java" means to most people.  Also, I am not aware of any 3rd party libraries that implement this.

Why?

The performance this "simplest possible" map is too poor for it to be useful to more than a handful of use-cases.  It has been stated by the Java team on numerous occasions that it is not their intention to implement all possible things in the standard libraries.